# Windows batch file renaming via reordering/manipulating current name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a large amount of files in multiple folders, the file name format is:

```
FILE DESCRIPTION_MM DD YYYY_F_XXXXX.EXTENSION
```

The `FILE DESCRIPTION` is a variable amount of characters. `XXXXX` is a variable amount of characters as well. The extension is either `pdf`, `doc` or `docx`. The delimiter to be used is the first instance of `_`. Example:

```
Foo File_01 01 2016_F_Bar.pdf
```

I need to rename each file by reordering the Date to the front. Instead of the current format, it needs to be

```
MM DD YYYY_FILE DESCRIPTION_F_XXXXX.EXTENSION".
```

Thus I need to cut out DATE and the 2nd instance of `_` and move it to the front of the filename. This amounts to 11 characters in total including the `_`.

The extension needs to be unchanged. Using the above example:

```
01 01 2016_Foo File_01 01 2016_F_Bar.pdf
```

Also I only want to rename the files in the format "FILE DESCRIPTION_MM DD YYYY_F_XXXXX.EXTENSION" ignoring all other cases in which files are already formatted with the DATE in the front and cases where there is no DATE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What did you try to achieve your goal?

Comment: If you're going to rename them all to put the date at the front, why not go all the way and [put the date in a sensible, standard, sortable format like YYYY-MM-DD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ? And, are you open to using PowerShell? It will make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try on some test data

```
@echo off

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s *_*_*.pdf *_*_*.doc *_*_*.docx ^|findstr /R /C:".*_[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_F_.*\."') DO (
    FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2* delims=_" %%H IN ("%%~nxG") DO rename "%%~G" "%%~I_%%~H_%%~J"
)
```

Comment: I tried running this script but I get the file not found error.

Comment: @Misterme , not sure what the problem is. I tested this but only with three files. Are you saying it does not work at all? What is the name of your batch file?

Comment: @Misterme I made an an error in my testing. The new edit above works fine for the essential task. It's still an issue that you have asked not to include files with dates or without dates at the start but only you know the range of text in the filenames, so reliable code can't be written. We'd have to guess - and then re-write the code when you came back and said "Oh, it didn't do xxx yyy and zzz filenames correctly."